# Get http post request progress for loading indicator

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-services, angular-http

I am building an angular 2 application. In this on submit of a page I am calling web service via HTTP POST and navigating to the next screen based on the service response.

During this I would like to show loading indicator that shows the progress of the service request. Both the i/p and o/p are of JSON format and doesn't involve any image uploading.

Is there any way of doing this? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just set a variable in your class when you start the HTTP request, reset it when the request is done. If the variable is set show the loader in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I would like to get and set the progress percentage value from 1 to 100. Is that possible ?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. There are a lot of factors, the most important is the time taken by the API. Now if your request is taking very long and the API supports some way of showing the percentage of completion of request, (some db state maybe) then you can have a polling requests from your front-end afer the first delaying HTTP request. The polling request will update the status of your progress bar. If your API supports socket connection then another connection will do the job for polling request

Answer (score 1):

If it is a larger request consider using the [reportProgress](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events). If it's a fast request I would just set an animation to be active while a variable you set to true when sending the request, and to false when you get a response.

Comment: Thanks Stol. But in my case its fast request. Is there any alternative of getting this progress ?

Comment: It depends on the payload I guess, if it's small enough to be a simple response from server there wouldn't be anything more to report than that the request has been sent and recieved. 0 -> 100%. If it is larger and takes more packages to transmit you could report the progress. Alternatively fake the animation so it looks as though it loads in percent even though it's a simple request